# How can I determine the probability that a sample has a certain average given details about the total population?

Tags: probability, sample, games

Imagine that I have goal scoring data for a hockey team. They average 2.43 goals scored per game with a standard deviation of 1.63 for this data set. They have played 82 games.

I have two subsets of this data set; each subset represents data for the team when a specific goalie is on the ice (Goalie A and Goalie B). Each goalie has played 41 games in no particular order.

When Goalie A has been on the ice, the team averages 2.92 goals per game.

When Goalie B has been on the ice, the team averages 2.00 goals per game.

Assume that the goalies have no influence on their own team's goal scoring rates.

What I am trying to understand is this: is there a way to compute the probability that a team could have data subsets that differ so greatly from one another? How likely is it that the team scores almost a full goal more with one goalie on the ice as compared to the other?

If anyone could set me on the right path for how a calculation like this might unfold, that would be great.

Comment: Is this a [tag:self-study] question? If so, I'd like to provide a hint, but you may want to review [our policy](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/12/32036) and add the tag.

Comment: Hi Nick. Thanks for the link. This is not a homework question, but rather a topic I'm very interested in. The data above are real-life numbers for the New Jersey Devils this season and I'm just hoping to understand it better. I did look at using confidence intervals and found ranges for 95% and 99%, but I wasn't very clear what the results were telling me.